# How can i have a if statement in my Accelerometer reading, That only the highest reading in Z axis appears on screen when i throw upward my phone?

Tags: javascript, php, android, html

Whenever i throw my phone the highest reading of the z-axis appears and then stops and doesn't anymore read the next movement of my phone.

Here's my Script for you to see :

```
<script>

function handleAccelerometer(event) {
  var x = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);
  var y = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y);
  var z = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z);
  var acce = 'Acceleration:<br />';
  acce += 'x: ' + x +'<br />y: ' + y + '<br />z: ' + z + '<br />';
  accelerometer.innerHTML = acce;

}

function stopAccelerometer(event){
  window.removeEventListener("devicemotion", handleAccelerometer);
}

function reloadAccelerometer(event){
  location.reload();
}

function init() {
  var accelerometer = document.getElementById('accelerometer');
  var button = document.getElementById("stop");
  if(window.DeviceMotionEvent) {
  window.addEventListener('devicemotion', handleAccelerometer);     
  button.addEventListener("click", stopAccelerometer)
  }
}

window.onload = init;
```

Comment: check your phone, your phone may damaged.

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla may damage of what? of throwing it upward?

Comment: May be your getting number format exception. So it's might be treminated flow. remove parseint and try it once

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla sorry but I'm only new to java and I don't really understand what you are saying,thanks.

Comment: replace below lines with
  var x = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);
  var y = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y);
  var z = parseInt(event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z);
this code

  var x = (event.accelerationIncludingGravity.x);
  var y = (event.accelerationIncludingGravity.y);
  var z = (event.accelerationIncludingGravity.z);

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla at first my code was like that, but may teacher said that it must be a whole number.

Comment: You have to convert, but some times you will get NaN also., Then check isNumber then do convert to Int or else show error

Comment: @JitendraKumar.Balla that script is working properly, I'm only just finding the highest reading of the z-axis when my phone is moving.

Comment: Great (y).. Good work....